# Laravel Intervention ImageServiceProvider not found

Tags: laravel, imagem

Estou enfrentando um problema com a lib Intervention/Image onde eu realmente estou sem ideias do que pode estar acontecendo e como resolver, as pesquisas que eu fiz na internet não me levaram a nada além das próprias explicações informadas no site do desenvolvedor, o complicado é que isto funciona no meu ambiente local com as mesmas configurações, com a exceção do composer que localmente esta na 1.8.0.

```
Meu servidor online
-- Composer version 1.8.5
-- Laravel version 5.8
-- PHP version 7.3.0
-- Fileinfo support ativo
-- GD Support ativo / Version bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
-- Imagick PHP extension não instalada
```

Como fiz localmente, eu segui exatamente as instruções informada no site do desenvolvedor.

```
php composer.phar require intervention/image
Add config/app.php $providers: Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
Add config/app.php $alias: 'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

Aqui que começa o problema.

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"
```

Quando rodo o comando eu recebo a seguinte mensagem.

```
[waservice@web7081 portal]$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found
```

Aqui está o retorno do dump-autoload:

```
[waservice@web7081 ~]$ php composer.phar dump-autoload
Generated autoload files containing 0 classes
```

Retorno do autoload otimizado:

```
[waservice@web7081 ~]$ php composer.phar dump-autoload -o
Generated optimized autoload files containing 156 classes
```

Parte que informo o intervention no composer.json

```
"require": {
   "php": "^7.1.3",
   "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
   "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
   "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
   "intervention/image": "dev-master"
},
```

Retorno do update do composer.

```
[waservice@web7081 ~]$ php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Retorno do composer install

```
[waservice@web7081 ~]$ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Retorno do meu intervention install

```
[waservice@web7081 ~]$ php composer.phar require intervention/image
Using version ^2.4 for intervention/image
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Na vendor existe a pasta intervention, eu realmente estou sem saída aqui. Alguém pode dar uma luz.

Comment: Opa Max, você já tentou instalar um projeto novo do laravel e depois instalar o pack? (Pra testar)
Ou, tenta rodar o composer update e depois instalar o pack

Comment: Sim, inclusive essa última vez eu fiz todos os update, dump e o que tinha mais pra fazer antes de baixar a lib da intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou remover a pasta vendor e instalar novamente com o composer?

- `rm -rf vendor`
- `composer install`

Comment: Sem sucesso amigo, ele até refez o download do intervention e tals.. mas o erro persiste.